# How to add the gallery images to property-print.php on Essential real Estate wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I have been trying to display the images of the gallery (not only the property thumbnail) on the pdf generated (on property-print.php template) on the print icon but i can't manage to do it.

last thing i tried was this:

```
<?php

$property_gallery = ere_get_property_gallery_images();

if ( $property_gallery ) {

    echo '<div class="property-gallery">';

    foreach ( $property_gallery as $image ) {

        echo '<img src="' . $image . '" />';

    }

    echo '</div>';

}

?>
```

But it just returns a blank pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is return blank pdf because it found fatal error
Try the following code:

```
<?php
$property_gallery = get_post_meta($property_id, ERE_METABOX_PREFIX . 'property_images', true);

if ($property_gallery) :
    $property_gallery = explode('|', $property_gallery);
?>
    <div class="property-gallery">
        <?php
        $gallery_id = 'ere_gallery-' . rand();
        foreach ($property_gallery as $image) :
            $image_src = ere_image_resize_id($image, 1920, 1080, true);
            if (!empty($image_src)) {
        ?>
                <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image_src) ?>" width="1160" height="500">
            <?php } ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```